# jQuery on hover show for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that contains multiple lines like this each wrapped within `<div id="result">`;

```
<div id="result"><a href="http://www.domain.com/">Link Name</a><iframe src="http://www.domain.com/" style="width:285px;height:285px;border:0px;margin:0px" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

I am currently using the following jQuery to display the `<a>` tag on hover;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result iframe').hover(function(){
        $('#result a').fadeIn(200);
    },function(){
        $('#result a').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

However, the hover only works on the first `<div id="result">` and also shows the `<a>` tags for every `<div id="result">` rather than just the one the user hovered on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use classes, IDs can't ocurre more than once in a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this - Changing `results` to a class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.result').hover(function(){ // <-- change to class.. and bind to wrapper div
        $(this).find('a').fadeIn(200);
    },function(){
        $(this).find('a').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your weird thing :

**Html**

```
    <div class="result">
        <a href="http://www.domain.com/" style="display:none;">Link Name</a>
        <iframe src="http://www.domain.com/" style="width:285px;height:285px;border:0px;margin:0px;background:red;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <a href="http://www.domain.com/" style="display:none;">Link Name</a>
        <iframe src="http://www.domain.com/" style="width:285px;height:285px;border:0px;margin:0px;background:red;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.result iframe').hover(function(e) {
   $(this).parent().find('a').fadeIn(); 
}, function() {
     $(this).parent().find('a').fadeOut();   
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/CgGjN/4/)

Edit with hover.

Nb: `e.preventDefault();` on click event if you don't want the link to submit by clicking.

Comment: Kinda weird don't you think? Whats the point of the link fading in on mouseenter of the image if you will never be able to click the link since it fades out on mouseleave

Comment: re-edited but it's really weird and your link is veryy long to load... Maybe you should do that on a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#result iframe').hover(function(){
    $('#result a').fadeIn(200);
    $('#result a').fadeOut(200);
});
});
```

Comment: Sorry @reinder but i don't know what .fadein or fadeout do. is that the problem in my code. I was just making a general statement. Please correct me so that i don't do it wrongly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch only the `<a>` tags not for every, but for a specific `<div id="result">`, you can try to specify that in your jQuery code, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result:nth-child(1) iframe').hover(function(){
        $('#result:nth-child(1) a').fadeIn(200);
    },function(){
         $('#result:nth-child(1) a').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

So this will target only the first div with id="result". Catch the others by changing nth-child(0) - nth-child(1) - nth-child(2) ...

Another solution:
You can also set an id for every `<a>` tag or also, you can use a class to catch the specific element you need.